# jquery Flexigrid cell template

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, flexigrid

I'm using jquery flexigrid in my asp.net mvc app and fetching the data with a json call, and would like to ask if it is possible to have a cell which contains something like two divs with each div containing a diffenebt model string,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that. In the controller that's in charge of returning the data to the flexigrid, just return the div html, instead of only the cell's value.